# How do I prevent shipping price from being discounted when applied to cart?

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

My cart in 1.9.2.2 is discounting the shipping cost for some reason. Set at a flat $ 25 and when applied to cart, it equals $ 23.07. Have tried different amounts and different shipping methods with the same result. Calculating an unwanted discount for shipping by approximately 8%? 
Thanks!

Comment: is there a tax associated with your shipping method? Are you able to upload a screenshot of the shipping rate config

Comment: Ahhhh, did not think to look in the tax area because it was reducing the amount. Thanks so much for setting me on the correct path! Really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: No Problems hope it helps.

Comment: All set! Sorry I forgot to say it was fixed. Had me going in circles. Thanks again.

Comment: awesome! Just added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in comments:

Looks to be like there is tax associated with your shipping method